# Python not returning what I expected

Tags: python

Third day of learning Python. Code is not returning what I expected. I am working on an code that shows passengers added and passengers not added to flight. If I remove "no avaiable seats," code will return passengers added. I am trying to get both added passengers and no seats available to return.

```py
class Flight():
     def __init__(self, capacity):
         self.capacity = capacity
         self.passengers = []

     def add_passenger(self, name):
        if not self.open_seats():
            return False
        self.passengers.append(name)
        return True

     def open_seats(self):
        return self.capacity - len(self.passengers)

flight = Flight(3)

people = ["Huey", "Duey", "Luey", "Uncle Scrooge",]
for person in people:
    success = flight.add_passenger(person)
if success:
    print(f"Added {person} to flight successfully")
else:
    print(f"No available seats for {person}")
```

Comment: Did you mean to indent the last four lines to be within the `for` loop?

Comment: The issue with your code is the indentation of the if-else block. It's currently outside the for loop, so it only checks the success of adding the last person in the people list. You should indent the if-else block to be inside the for loop so that it checks the success for each person.

Comment: Please update the question with the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: Agreed, indentation of the for loop and below lines are required

Comment: The indention was the problem. I didn't even realize that this would cause a problem. Thank you so much for y'alls replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your If and Else statements should be on the same indentation as success, since you're using the iterating variable in the "no available seats" statement.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. The indention was the issue. Didn't even know it would cause such issues.

Comment: No problem! Try to have fun in your coding adventures!

Comment: Thanks! I'm enjoying it so far. Have a good one.